# c# How to pass parameter in a type specific constructor?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm creating a web service(wcf). I need to pass parameter to a constructor in that web service anybody suggest me a way to do that. . . .

Comment: What do you mean by *parameter to a constructor*, can you show an example ?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how a client can call a service with a constructor that takes in arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interface called IInstanceProvider that is responsible for the creation and caching of service instances.  Implement this class than create a service behavior to inject it in.  It would be way easier though to just leave paramterless and do whatever initialization to get these parameters that you passing in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx
http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/02/21/custom-servicehostfactory-for-wcf-and-iis.aspx